ImportError: Could not import chromadb python package. Please install it with `pip install chromadb`
I am trying to build a Chat PDF application using langchain,
During this I installed all the necessary packages, but there is one issue with this chromadb, which no matter what I do, it keeps showing the error.
I installed it, ran it many times, but I keep getting this error asking to install chromadb and
here is the screenshot of the error
repo link
I tried uninstalling and installing again, GPTed, saw issues in Github but nothing seems to help me fix the issue

Try with Python 3.10 and it worked

Try upgrading Chormadb version
pip install --upgrade chromadb


I think its something to do with the version. Chromadb currently dont support python 3.11, try downgrading

Thanks, I tried with python 3.10 and it worked.

If you would import it directly:
import chromadb
You would get:
raise ImportError('email-validator version >= 2.0 required, run pip install -U email-validator')
After updating email-validator - everything was fixed
